# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] when importing excel files into pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am getting a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'census_data.xlsx' " when importing excel file into pandas. I double checked my file was correct but I still get this error.

Here's my code:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('census_data.xlsx')

for sheet in book.sheets():
print (sheet.name)
```

Comment: `for sheet in book.sheets():`

Comment: Since I can't close as off topic, I'll close as a dupe which explains how to do it right. Use any of the answers in the marked dupe. Honestly, it isn't hard to understand the root of the problem by reading the message the syntax error returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python should give you the line number that the error was found on in tracebacks. In this case, the error is in your `for` loop:

```
for sheet in book.sheets():
    ...
```

Note the space between `sheet` and `in`.